# pointing multiple subdomains using wildcards to a folder

Tags: apache2, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, virtual-hosts

I want to use wildcards to send the request to any sobdomains to the folder of the domain.please specify how to achieve this in apache2 using the virtual host settings.The domain and its subdomain uses the same IP address. the subdomains cannot be predetermined as they are created by users.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about this configuration

```
<VirtualHost *.domain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```